# Validation and Testing in Tensforflow Estimator vs. Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-estimator

I've read answers [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set) and trying to understand how `training`, `validation` and `testing` map to Tensorflow Estimator API and Keras API.

**A: Tensorflow**

`tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate` function takes a `train_spec` and a `eval_spec`.

Here, does `evaluate` mean `validation` or `testing` in above terminology? 
If it's `testing`, where do I specify a `validation set`?

**B: Keras**

In Keras, this seems to be clearer, `model.fit` takes `validation_data` argument, which is for `validation set`. There is a separate function `model.evaluate`, to which we provide the `test set`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

In practice the terms "test set" and "validation set" are used interchangeably (flipped from how they are described above). As a result it's become common to refer to the one that is used during training to be referred to as either the test/validation set. To disambiguate, the set that gets set aside for hyperparameter tuning (here described as the validation set) is generally referred to as the holdout set.([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_test,_and_validation_sets))

Based on this definition you can do one simple thing. For example suppose that, the first dataset is "train", the second is "validation"(as in keras) for real-time evaluation of the model at each step and the final dataset is the "test".
you can simply check the model once it finished training by running the model.predict on the test dataset, to see how your model works on the unseen data.